# CSS transition not applied to max-height switching on UL list

Tags: javascript, css, html-lists, transition, nav

I cannot determine why the specified transition is not applied when I toggle the max-height of the unordered list. The toggle is accomplished by switching classes on the UL. I've tried putting the transition in the max-height classes, but to no avail. I've created a [working example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TomJS/07cgn26r/), and the code is supplied below in full. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
    <title>Transition Problem</title>
<style>
.nav ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 2s;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 2s;
    white-space: normal;
}

.max-height-150 {
    max-height: 150px;
}

.max-height-none {
    max-height: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>The JavaScript switches the class correctly, and the height of the UL switches as expected, but the transition is not applied.</p>
<button>SWITCH CLASS</button>
<nav class="nav">
    <ul class="max-height-150">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
        <li>Item 7</li>
        <li>Item 8</li>
        <li>Item 9</li>
        <li>Item 10</li>
        <li>Item 11</li>
        <li>Item 12</li>
        <li>Item 13</li>
        <li>Item 14</li>
        <li>Item 15</li>
        <li>Item 16</li>
        <li>Item 17</li>
        <li>Item 18</li>
        <li>Item 19</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<script>
// Select the button:
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

// Toggle between the two max-height classes when the button is clicked:
var buttonClickListener = function (e) {
    var navUl = document.querySelectorAll('.nav ul')[0];
    if (navUl.classList.contains('max-height-150')) {
        navUl.classList.remove('max-height-150');
        navUl.classList.add('max-height-none');
    } else {
        navUl.classList.add('max-height-150');
        navUl.classList.remove('max-height-none');
    }
    e.preventDefault();
};

// Add a click listener on the button and register the toggle function on it:
if (button.addEventListener) {
    button.addEventListener('click', buttonClickListener, false);
} else if (button.attachListener) {
    button.attachEvent('click', buttonClickListener);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot transition from a set max-height to none (or auto, or 100%, etc). You can only transition between set numbers. Try setting the new max height to the largest value you believe it will have and it should work the way you want.

```
.max-height-none {
    max-height: 350px;
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/07cgn26r/1/

Comment: Thanks! The only problem is that the beginning of the transition from a greater max-height to a lesser max-height has a "delay" that is actually time spent covering the difference between the actual height of the element and the max-height specified. (e.g., try max-height: 10000px instead of 350px). Is there a way to add the max-height dynamically (to the true full height) with JavaScript and still obtain the transition effect?

Answer (score 0):

Use the viewport!

```
.max-height-none {
    max-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly, this won't work if the content is taller than the viewport. I need it to open to reveal the complete content, regardless of the height of the content.